# Confusion between a general global variable and object as a variable in javaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, jsobject

Below is my code. When I'm calling `myDate` variable outside of `myTime()` function to create a `Date()` object, the `setInterval()` function don't fire but when it's inside `myTime()` function. As I know `myDate` variable is a global variable and it should work same inside or outside of the function. But why here the `setInterval()` method not firing while I'm creating the `Date()` object outside of the function? Experts explain the things. TIA

```
var myDate = new Date();
    function myTime(){
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds();
    }
    setInterval(myTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right: `myDate` variable is accessible from `myTime()` function, but if it is declared outside of it, its value doesn't change. In the following snippet i've created one more external variable `i` to show that it is accessible from within the function:

```js
var myDate = new Date();
var i = 0;
function myTime() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds() + " (" + i++ + ")";
}
setInterval(myTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

On the other hand, if you declare `myDate` variable inside the function, it will be created each time function is called - every second:

```js
function myTime() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds();
}
setInterval(myTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: updated the question. maybe it will help you to better understand.

Comment: @AshikurRahman why do you think that `setInterval()` doesn't fire?

Comment: If you run the first snippet you will se that `i` changes every second

Comment: yes, but then the seconds not changing as interval time? I'm new in programming

Comment: @AshikurRahman _“but if it is declared outside of it, its value doesn't change”_.

Comment: Right, the seconds not changing because you don't change them - you create this variable only once and it holds the same value